# Get all values not in another column of same table and another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get all index which are not in other column of same table and other column of two other table.
My query is working fine.
Is there any other way to get same results faster?

`SELECT Index
        FROM temptable A
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 
                            from temptable B
                            where A.Index = B.Index2) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM temptable2 B
                            WHERE A.Index = B.INDEX) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM temptable3 B
                            WHERE A.Index = B.INDEX) 
        AND type = 'G';`

Comment: what do you mean by index? Is it the Oracle index or a column name called index?

Comment: Really a bad idea to use a ORACLE reserverd Key word as column name.

Comment: Ignore that , I am not using that name in my project.

Comment: @user2257655:I think this is fine , i dont know ,but if there is an index on all the index column of the table it will fetch the data faster.

Comment: @user2257655:do we have "index" in index column ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this [example](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Replacing where not exist with left join will give you better performance

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this will fetch data faster or not ,but it will depend on the indexes created on the index column .If the index column is primary key then it will definitely do `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` even for unique/non unique  index it return such result.

```
 SELECT Index
    FROM temptable A
 WHERE  type = 'G';
 MINUS   
  (select index2 
     from temptable B
    union  
    SELECT index
    FROM temptable2 B
    union
    SELECT index
    FROM temptable3 B
   ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: I have not tested, since i dont have resource

```
SELECT
      TABLE1.INDEX
FROM
          (SELECT INDEX FROM TEMPTABLE WHERE TYPE = 'G') TABLE1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPTABLE TT1 ON TABLE1.INDEX = TT1.INDEX2
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPTABLE2 TT2 ON TABLE1.INDEX = TT2.INDEX
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPTABLE3 TT3 ON TABLE1.INDEX = TT3.INDEX
WHERE
      TT2.COLUMNB IS NULL;

Add indexes on the `columns TEMPTABLE.INDEX, TEMPTABLE.INDEX2, TEMPTABLE2.INDEX, TEMPTABLE3.INDEX`
```